# Equivalent of swift code in firebase to objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

Firebase suggested to use this to support multiple environments when you only have a single target. This is on swift though, what would it be on objective c since the appledelegate.m in react-native doesnt use swift.

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyGoogleService", ofType: "plist")
guard let fileopts = FIROptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath)
  else { assert(false, "Couldn't load config file") }
FIRApp.configure(with: fileopts)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Objective-C you can write like this way.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyGoogleService" ofType:@"plist"];
FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```